# From datetime to timestamp python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timestamp

I need to convert a datetime object with microsecond resolution to a timestamp, the problem is that I don't get the same timestamp second's resolution.

For example the timestamp that I pass as an argument is 1424440192 and I get in return 1424429392.011750, why is this?, I Only changed microsecond value of the datetime object, so I expect to change only values after the dot. 
PD: In this example I'm only simulating one timestamp.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def totimestamp(dt, epoch=datetime(1970,1,1)):
    td = dt - epoch

    return td.total_seconds()
    #return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) *
    #10**6) / 1e6


timestamp_pc = 1424440192

tm = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_pc)
new_tm = tm.replace(microsecond = 11750)

print tm
print new_tm
print timestamp_pc
print "%f " %(totimestamp(new_tm))
```

Comment: What does a `print totimestamp(tm)` show if you put right between the lines with `tm = datetime.fromtimestamp ...` and `new_tm = tm.replace...` ?

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`fromtimestamp` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

> If optional argument tz is None or not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and time, and the returned datetime object is naive.

Since your `totimestamp` function does not do the same timezone adjustment in reverse, the time is wrong by your time zone offset.

Answer (score 2):

I get it.
I changed 
`tm = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_pc)`
for
`tm = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp_pc)`

and now timestamp are identical.